# Separar Datos de una BD

Tags: php, postgresql

tengo una consulta si es que alguien me puede ayudar, resulta que tengo una tabla en postgresql, en la cual aparecen cod_storbox, este dato vienen 3 codigos separados por un "/" o a veces solo uno sin /

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que que quiero hacer es hacer una lista o tabla en php, la cual buscará por rango de fecha de cierre y me listará todos los cod_storbox ingresados en ese rango, pero quiero que cuando sean 2 o mas codigos los separe en 3 filas diferentes y no los muestre en una sola.

[image: ejemplo En la BD: Dato 1 = 11-1 / 11-2 / 11-3 Dato 2 = 21-1 Lo que quiero: Tabla o Lista Fila 1 = 11-1 Fila 2 = 11-2]

Comment: A ver si te funciona esta idea, recorres el resultado de la consulta y vas construyendo la tabla, cuando obtienes la columna cod_storbox, haces un explode https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php con (/) y obtienes un array con los diferentes valores de la columna. Una vez construido el array con los diferentes cod_storbox lo recorres y vas añadiendo filas a la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciónes [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) y [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) están una debajo de la otra en la documentación desde PG 9.0, lo cual es extrañamente significativo porque la combinación de ambas soluciona tu caso de uso.

#### unnest

Dado un array

```
SELECT ARRAY['codigo1','codigo2','codigo3'] as codigos
```

cuya salida es

| codigos |
| --- |
| {codigo1,codigo2,codigo3} |

La función `unnest` convierte cada elemento del array en un registro

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['codigo1','codigo2','codigo3']) as codigo
```

| codigo |
| --- |
| codigo1 |
| codigo2 |
| codigo3 |

#### string_to_array

A su vez, dado un texto

```
SELECT 'codigo1/codigo2/codigo3' AS texto_inicial
```

la función `string_to_array(string_original, divisor)`  convierte un texto en array

```
SELECT string_to_array('codigo1/codigo2/codigo3') AS textos_array
```

Por lo tanto, dada una tabla o subconsulta 'datos_origen' cuya salida sea

| fec_cierre | cod_storebox |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | codigo1/codigo2/codigo3 |
| 2021-02-03 | codigo4 |
| 2021-03-06 | codigo5 |

La consulta

```
 SELECT fec_cierre,  
        unnest( string_to_array(cod_storebox, '/')) AS codigo
 FROM datos_origen
```

Entrega

| fec_cierre | codigo |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | codigo1 |
| 2021-01-01 | codigo2 |
| 2021-01-01 | codigo3 |
| 2021-02-03 | codigo4 |
| 2021-03-06 | codigo5 |

### [<kbd>link ejemplo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/68604/0)

Si quieres filtrar sobre esa query por fecha, no hay problema en poner

```
 SELECT fec_cierre,  
        unnest( string_to_array(cod_storebox, '/')) AS codigo
 FROM datos_origen
 WHERE fec_cierre<'20210228'::date
```

Que eliminaría a `código5` del resultado

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda me sirvió mucho :)